# App not being installed on device after changing machine

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, appinstaller

I have a project, which was running clean and good, later I changed my machine and now from the new machine whenever I build the APK and install it on a physical device. it shows app not installed and the thing i did from my co-workers machine the app got installed.

I tried deleting the project and cloned it again from GitHub, I tried invalidate/caches restart, but it did not solved the problem.

Comment: you are install app directly from android studio or apk

Comment: provide logs which you are getting while installing apk

Comment: @NeerajSingh I build the APK and installed it

Comment: By running the project works fine

Comment: hmm you are installing apk directly from android studio or copy apk in device then install. can you attached error msg

Comment: are you missing the `debug.keystore` file?  was it ignored in the `.gitignore`?

Comment: @kenmistry where is the debug.keystore file? anyways I checked my gitignore it was not there

Comment: it is in the `android/app/`, is it not? this happened to me once while switching between machines. my `.gitignore` file had this entry `*.keystore` and i had an issue with `app:installDebug`. i can be wrong here unless you share your error logs.

Comment: Don't rebuild the project and install apk from outputs, Instead build the apk from build menu and then copy and install apk from outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem, I just uninstalled and re-installed Android Studio which solved my problem, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem once, i found like adb driver was missing in my case.
You can also try after instating this universal adb driver then restart computer.

http://adbdriver.com/

Just give this try and let me know i also have other solution in mind as a suggestion.

Comment: if the drivers are missing you can't even see the device let alone install the app on it

Comment: Can you please share more detail of error log from android studio?

Comment: that comment makes no sense

Comment: We can do this ... for that if you like please share logs

Comment: that comment also makes no sense